# Why does "iMillis" appear when serializing of Joda-Time Duration?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, jodatime

I want to serialize a Joda-Time `Duration` instance as a long representing the number of seconds using `Gson`.  My serializer class is:

```
private class DurationSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Duration>
{
  public JsonElement serialize(Duration duration,
                               Type durationType,
                               JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
    return new JsonPrimitive(duration.getStandardSeconds());
    }
}
```

The output of this is `{"iMillis":900000}`.  I just want the number of seconds, not the iMillis tag.  Is that possible?

Comment: How did you configure (plug in) the serializer into Gson so that it is invoked for serializing Duration? Are you sure it is actually invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using `JsonDeserializer` as it's been deprecated in favor of the Streaming API. I'm not sure what your problem is, but I don't think it's in the `Serializer`.

Try using [`TypeAdapter`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) instead:

```
public class DurationTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Duration> {
  public void write(JsonWriter writer, Duration value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      writer.nullValue();
      return;
    }

    writer.value(duration.getStandardSeconds());
  }

  // implementation of read() is left as an exercise to you
}
```

Register it like this:

```
GsonBuidler builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(new DurationTypeAdapter());
Gson g = builder.create();
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I have, except my field is named duration.  The full field comes out as "duration":{"iMillis":604800000}.  What I want is "duration":604800000.  I don't have the name iMillis anywhere in my code.  Thanks.